# passing char to function in c (is the book wrong?)

Tags: objective-c, c, char

I'm reading the book `"Objective-C Programming The Big Nerd Ranch Guide"`.

---

They give out this code:

```
void congratulateStudent(char student, char course, int numDays)
{
printf("%s has done as much %s Programming as I could fit into %d days.\n", student, course, numDays);
}
```

and **call** it with this:

```
congratulateStudent("Mark", "Cocoa", 5);
```

This gives me this warning:

```
Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char'
```

---

Is the book wrong?

Comment: The book is about objective-c, they first teach you c

Comment: Perhaps [there has been an update to the book](http://books.google.ch/books?id=Mqu-mnXZAi8C&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=congratulateStudent&source=bl&ots=jSvBEoJvy8&sig=druPNA-L6Uo3iJDoAcedzXqoxcU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=K-B1UO6QJIv14QSBh4CwDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=congratulateStudent&f=false)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's not correct. Perhaps a print error. Just make them pointers:

```
void congratulateStudent(char* student, char* course, int numDays)
```

Technically, it's undefined behaviour in C to pass incorrect format string to `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a typo.

`Char` means only one character in single quotes, as `'a'`.

A constant string is in double quotes and decays into a `char*` or character pointer, like this.

```
"Hello World"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes if this is what the book says to do it is definitely a mistake it should be char * as the parameters in the method like the warning says.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the book has a typo.

You should use `char*` instead of `char` for both parameters of your C function